# Send commands over SSH to server

Tags: python, ssh

Here's a very small and basic script that sends commands over SSH to another computer on my network:

```
#!/bin/python
import sys, os
commands = ""
for i in sys.argv[1:]:
        commands += " " + i;

if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        os.system("sshpass -p VerySecrectPassword ssh pi@172.16.0.141")
else:
        os.system("sshpass -p VerySecrectPassword ssh pi@172.16.0.141" + commands)
```

Am I being very "Pythonic"? Is it better to use a for loop to join all the commands or the join function?

```
commands = " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
```

Personally, I think the for loop reads better, but that's just my opinion and I'm a newbie. Which is considered the better way to do things?

Furthermore:

- Are there any other areas in this script that could be improved?
- Is it a bad idea to store the password in the script (located at /usr/bin)?

**Note:** This script is stored on a computer where I am the only user (except root).

Comment: See this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586106/perform-commands-over-ssh-with-python

Comment: Why not trying to use paramiko

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To answer your questions: *Yes*.

Your code could be boiled down to:

```
#!/bin/python
import sys
import os

os.system("sshpass -p VerySecrectPassword ssh pi@172.16.0.141" + " " .join(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Note that I also put the imports on two lines, as recommended by [PEP8, Python's official style-guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

But I would actually re-expand it to:

```
#!/bin/python
import sys
import os

data = {"user": "pi",
        "host": "172.16.0.141",
        "password": "VerySecret",
        "commands": " " .join(sys.argv[1:])}

command = "sshpass -p {password} ssh {user}@{host} {commands}"
os.system(command.format(**data))
```

This gives you some easier ways to modify the configuration. It would also be easier to implement reading this configuration from a file now.

Note that bash (or whatever shell you use) will not care about the trailing whitespace in case `commands` is the empty string.

The next step would be using a ssh library, like @Simon recommended in his comment.

One way to do it would be first setting up [password-less login](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id) and then using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3586168/4042267) and a comment within it:

```
#!/bin/python
import sys
import paramiko

rpi = {"username": "pi",
       "hostname": "172.16.0.141"}
command = " " .join(sys.argv[1:])}

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(**rpi)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
```

Here the `ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())` is needed because paramiko [does not read the hosts file correctly](https://github.com/onyxfish/relay/issues/11).

Comment: you could also take the password from an environment variable, which is probably better than  having it in the source code

Comment: Does that work out of the box or do you have to set up the config file?

Comment: Nice. Thought it just loaded the optional config file att first  i.e. .ssh/config